# How to download by block with Qt?

Tags: qt, byte, qnetworkaccessmanager

For many reasons i need to download file by piece of 1024 byte.

I find nothing in QnetworkAccessManager.
I can not use the "header technic" because my server don't support it.

*I call header technic, the tecnic who send stuff like "Content-Range: bytes 21010-47000/47022" in the header of http request*

Comment: Is the 1024 byte a client or server limitation?

Comment: a client limitation (it's designed for a mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `QTcpSocket` instead and call `QTcpSocket::setReadBufferSize()` with an appropriate value. Then you won't be able to read bigger chunks than the size of the buffer you set.

Comment: Thank you, in fact i find an other solution :

i use qnetworkreply::setReadBufferSize()

That's cool

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractsocket.html#setReadBufferSize